# replacing words

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to replace the first and last words of the sentence which I typed in the console.

if I type the following sentence in console:

```
London is the Capital of UK.
```

I need such result

```
UK is the capital of London.
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but one way is to use the .Split method on this whole string sentence to split it into an array, you put space " " as a separator, then save the first word into a variable, then save the second word into a variable, then replace the first with the last and then the last with the first. Then use the .Join method to convert back to string. Please post your effort here, Stackoverflow is not meant to have the whole code ready for you.

Comment: You need to define the term 'word'. Or rely on regex's understanding..

Answer (score 1):

You could use following method and `String.Split` + `String.Join`:

```
public static void SwapFirstAndLast<T>(IList<T>? items)
{
    if (items == null || items.Count < 2) return;
    T first = items[0];
    items[0] = items.Last();
    items[^1] = first;
}
```

---

```
string sentence = " London is the Capital of UK";
string[] wordDelimiters = { " " };
string[] words = sentence.Trim().Split(wordDelimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
SwapFirstAndLast(words);
sentence = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

In more *generic* case when we should take punctuation into account, e.g.

```
   London, being a vast area, is the capital of UK =>

=> UK, being a vast area, is the capital of London
```

we can use *regular expressions* to match words. Assuming that word is a
sequence of letters and apostrophes we can use

```
[\p{L}']+
```

pattern and do the following:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string text = "London, being a vast area, is the capital of UK";

// All words matched
var words = Regex.Matches(text, @"[\p{L}']+");

// Replace matches: first into last, 
// last into first, all the others keep intact
int index = -1;

var result = Regex.Replace(
    text,
  @"[\p{L}']+",
    m => {
       index += 1;

       if (index == 0)
         return words[^1].Value;
       if (index == words.Count - 1)
         return words[0].Value;
       return m.Value;
    });
``
```